# Datatable editing with webix

Tags: webix

I try to set ON the datatable editing but I don't know why it doesn't work. check

```
var datatable = webix.ui({
    id: "mytable",
    container: "myDATA",
view:"datatable",
autoheight:true,
select: 'row',
multiselect: true,
autoConfig:true,
editable: true,
editaction: 'dblclick',
columns:[
    { id:"rank",    header: translate["en"].rank,              width:50},
    { id:"title",   header: translate["en"].title,  width:200},
    { id:"year",    header: translate["en"].year,      width:80},
    { id:"votes",   header: translate["en"].votes,         width:100}
],
on: {
  onBeforeLoad: function() {
    this.showOverlay('Loading...');
  },
  onAfterLoad: function() {
    if(!this.count()) {
      this.showOverlay('No data found...');
    } else {
      this.hideOverlay();
    }           
  },
  onItemClick: function(id,element,node) {
    var row = this.getItem(id);
    console.log(row);
  }
}
```

});

my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gdjaero9/40/ any solutions ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to set [the editor](http://docs.webix.com/desktop__editing.html) for each column :

```
columns:[
        { id:"rank",    header: translate["en"].rank, width:50},
        { id:"title",   header: translate["en"].title, editor:'text', width:200},
        { id:"year",    header: translate["en"].year, editor:'text', width:80},
        { id:"votes",   header: translate["en"].votes, editor:'text', width:100}
    ],
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gdjaero9/44/

Answer (score 0):

Though you have already defined `editable: true`, but all the cells are still acting as DIVs. Becuase you haven't assigned the input components to your cells. To convert the div to text box on selecting the cell, you will have to provider the editor to that column.

There are various editors: text (converts the div to text box), select (converts the div to combo box), drowdown (converts the div to dropdown box) etc.

To add the editor in the column, add property:
`editor:'editor_type'`